# How to fill missing GPS Data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, gps, gis

I have a data frame that looks something like this

```
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+----+----------+----------+
|     | Actual_Lat | Actual_Long |          Time           | ID | Cal_long | Cal_lat  |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+----+----------+----------+
|   0 | 63.433376  | 10.397068   | 2019-09-30 04:48:13.540 | 11 | 10.39729 | 63.43338 |
|   1 | 63.433301  | 10.395846   | 2019-09-30 04:48:18.470 | 11 | 10.39731 | 63.43326 |
|   2 | 63.433259  | 10.394543   | 2019-09-30 04:48:23.450 | 11 | 10.39576 | 63.43323 |
|   3 | 63.433258  | 10.394244   | 2019-09-30 04:48:29.500 | 11 | 10.39555 | 63.43436 |
|   4 | 63.433258  | 10.394215   | 2019-09-30 04:48:35.683 | 11 | 10.39505 | 63.43427 |
| ... | ...        | ...         | ...                     | ...|      ... |      ... |
|  70 | NaN        | NaN         | NaT                     | NaN| 10.35826 | 63.43149 |
|  71 | NaN        | NaN         | NaT                     | NaN| 10.35809 | 63.43155 |
|  72 | NaN        | NaN         | NaT                     | NaN| 10.35772 | 63.43163 |
|  73 | NaN        | NaN         | NaT                     | NaN| 10.35646 | 63.43182 |
|  74 | NaN        | NaN         | NaT                     | NaN| 10.35536 | 63.43196 |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

`Actual_lat` and `Actual_long` contains GPS coordinates of data obtained from GPS device. `Cal_lat` and `cal_lat` are GPS coordinates obtained from `OSRM's API`. As you can see there is a lot of data missing in actual coordinates. I am looking to get a data set such that when I take difference of actual_lat vs cal_lat it should be zero or at least close to zero. I tried to fill these missing values with destination lat and long, but that would result in huge difference. My question is how can I fill these values using python/pandas so that when vehicle followed the OSRM estimated path the difference between actual lat/long and estimated lat/long should be zero or close to zero. I am new to GIS data Sets and have no idea about how to deal with them.

**EDIT**: I am looking for something like this.

```
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|     | Actual_Lat | Actual_Long |          Time           | Tour ID  | Cal_long | Cal_lat  | coordinates_diff_Lat | coordinates_diff_Lon |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   0 |  63.433376 |   10.397068 | 2019-09-30 04:48:13.540 |       11 | 10.39729 | 63.43338 |               -0.000 |               -0.000 |
|   1 |  63.433301 |   10.395846 | 2019-09-30 04:48:18.470 |       11 | 10.39731 | 63.43326 |                0.000 |               -0.001 |
|   2 |  63.433259 |   10.394543 | 2019-09-30 04:48:23.450 |       11 | 10.39576 | 63.43323 |                0.000 |               -0.001 |
|   3 |  63.433258 |   10.394244 | 2019-09-30 04:48:29.500 |       11 | 10.39555 | 63.43436 |               -0.001 |               -0.001 |
|   4 |  63.433258 |   10.394215 | 2019-09-30 04:48:35.683 |       11 | 10.39505 | 63.43427 |               -0.001 |               -0.001 |
| ... |        ... |         ... | ...                     |      ... |      ... |      ... |                  ... |                  ... |
|  70 |   63.43000 |    10.35800 | NaT                     | 115268.0 | 10.35826 | 63.43149 |                0.000 |               -0.003 |
|  71 |   63.43025 |    10.35888 | NaT                     | 115268.0 | 10.35809 | 63.43155 |                0.000 |               -0.003 |
|  72 |   63.43052 |    10.35713 | NaT                     | 115268.0 | 10.35772 | 63.43163 |                0.000 |               -0.002 |
|  73 |   63.43159 |    10.35633 | NaT                     | 115268.0 | 10.35646 | 63.43182 |                0.000 |               -0.001 |
|  74 |   63.43197 |    10.35537 | NaT                     | 115268.0 | 10.35536 | 63.43196 |                0.000 |                0.000 |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Note that `63.43197,10.35537` is destination and `63.433376,10.397068` is starting position. All these points represent road coordinates.

Comment: Could you show an example of your expected dataframe?

Comment: Wouldn't it be assumed that actual_lat and actual_long should be data that is measured and therefore not modifiable?

Comment: you could average the differences between Actual_lat and Cal_lat and use it to fill in the missing values ​​of the Actual_lat column

Comment: I have updated my question, maybe this would help

Comment: @ansev can you explain your 3rd comment with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need something like this:

I am taking the columns out of df as list.

```
div = float(len(cal_lat)) / float(len(actual_lat))

new_l = []
for i in range(len(cal_lat)):
    new_l.append(actual_lat[int(i/div)])

print(new_l)
len(new_l)
```

Do, the same with longitude columns.
Since these are GPS points you can tweak your model to have the accuracy of up to 3 digits, when taking the difference. So, keeping this in mind, starting from Actual_lat and lng , if your next value is same as the first, the difference won’t be much greater.
Hopefully, I made sense and you have your solution.

Comment: this is more like a pythonic way of doing it, but i get it. I did get what I wanted, will try with pandas approach. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need [pandas.DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html).

Let's say your dataframe is `df`, then you can do:

`df.Actual_Lat = df.Actual_Lat.where(~df.Actual_Lat.isna(), df.Cal_lat)`

Comment: "I tried to fill these missing values with destination lat and long, but that would result in huge difference"

Comment: Seems that I didn't really understand what the poster expected.

Comment: I just need to find a way where i can get missing values in sequence between two routes, which are equal in len of calculated route column. seems easy if these values are just some numbers, but here they represent coordinates.

Comment: Problem gets worse when actual_lat/long columns len is greater than cal_lat/long columns

Comment: Plz check my solution